# How to escape string variables when calling ExpandString in PowerShell

Tags: json, string, powershell, escaping

I have a PowerShell script to take a JSON file as a parameter and convert it to object. In the JSON string (as a template) there may have some variables which should be replaced with the actual values during runtime. For example, `$var_1`, `$var_x` and `$var_y` in this JSON string:

```
{
    "key1": "My name is ${var_1}",
    "key2":
    {
        "key3": "Another variable ${var_x}",
        "key4": "${var_y}"
    }
}
```

The names of these variables are unknown to the script. I use ExpandString to do the job:

```
[string]$jsonText = Get-Content $inputFile;

if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($jsonText)) {
    throw "No content in $inputFile"
}
$temp = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($jsonText);
$jsonObj = ConvertFrom-Json $temp;
```

The problem is, when a variable contains **double quotation mark**, then calling `ConvertFrom-Json` will fail because the quotation mark is not escaped. For example, `"My name is ${var_1}"` may become `"My name is a "new" name"`.

Is there a way to escape these string variables when calling ExpandString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following technique, **taking advantage of being able to embed *entire statements* in your template** via `$(...)` the subexpression operator; therefore, it should also be noted that you should generally **only use this technique with template strings that you *trust***, given that arbitrary commands could be executed.

```
$var_1 = '"new" name'

$template = @'
{ "key1": "My name is $((Get-Variable var_1).Value -replace '"', '\"')" }
'@

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

The above yields:

```
{ "key1": "My name is \"new\" name" }
```

which is valid JSON.

Note the use of `Get-Variable` to access the value of variable `${var_1}` *indirectly*, so that its embedded `"` chars. can be safely escaped as `\"`, as required by JSON.

---

Since the above is a little cumbersome for multiple references, you could define an **auxiliary function**:

```
$var_1 = '"new" name'

# Aux. function that takes a variable name and returns its value with
# " chars. \-escaped.
function esc ($varName) { (Get-Variable $varName).Value -replace '"', '\"' }    

# Now you can reference the variables using $(esc <var-name):
$template = @'
{ "key1": "My name is $(esc var_1)" }
'@

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

---

**If you don't control the template string**, more work is needed:

```
$var_1 = '"new" name'

# Aux. function that takes a variable name and returns its value with
# " chars. \-escaped.
function esc ($varName) { (Get-Variable $varName).Value -replace '"', '\"' }

# The original template with ${var}-style references.
$template = @'
{
  "key1": "My name is ${var_1}",
}
'@

# Modify the template to replace ${var} references with $(esc var).
$modifiedTemplate = $template -replace '\$\{(\w+)\}', '$$(esc $1)'

# Now expand the modified template.
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($modifiedTemplate)
```

Note that the template transformation assumes: <sup>Tip of the hat to [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) for his input.</sup>

- that there are no *escaped* variable references to be treated as literals in the input template (e.g., `` `${var} ``).
- that all variable references have the form `${varName}`, where `varName` is assumed to be composed of letters, digits, and underscores only (matching one or more `\w` instances).

A more robust solution that covers all edge cases may require using [PowerShell's parsing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psparser?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), which requires significantly more effort, however.

Answer (score 0):

Is it allowed in that format? If the variable is quoted with `""`, it's a string, and won't add the marks to `.json`. e.g.:

```
$var_1 = "Json Sample"
$json_piece = @"
{
    "key1": "My name is $var_1",
    "key2":
    {
        "key3": "Another variable $var_2",
        "key4": "$var_3"
    }
}
"@
```

It outputs (*$var_2 and $var_3 are not defined*):

```
{
    "key1": "My name is Json Sample",
    "key2":
    {
        "key3": "Another variable ",
        "key4": ""
    }
}
```

If you add `"` to a json file like this:

```
{
    "key1": "My name is "Json Sample"",
    "key2":
    {
        "key3": "Another variable ",
        "key4": ""
    }
}
```

You will make an error: *Excepted comma*. It means if the variable contains `""`, you must escape them at first, if not, the `.json` file is unexpected.

---

P.S. **Validation**
I validated it on [FREEFORMATTER.COM](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html).
It's my code:

```
{
  "Key": "value is "value"",
  "key2": "other value"
}
```

And I get 2 errors:

> - The JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Unexpected token v at position 20.
> - The JSON input is NOT valid in JavaScript, missing } after property list (At line #2), (At position #24)

Comment: The point is that here it's like `$var_1='"JsonSample"'`, so once the replacement happens, the resulting JSON does become invalid. They don't know what _value_ the variable will actually contain at run-time.

Comment: If you use `"` in your `.json` file, you will get errors. `"` must be escaped before passing to the `.json` file. I just tried that.

Comment: I added the validation to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but you seem to be restating the problem posed in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I found that, the point of this question is `how to escape double quotation mark` from the variable. @mklement0 made a good answer.